# How to mount with uid and gid using NFS?

Tags: nfs, nfs4, amazon-efs

I would like to mount an AWS EFS location with the efs driver which internaly uses nfs. Now the question is: How do I automatically mount a location with specific uid and gid? With sshfs e.g. I would just define uid, gid as mount options, but it's not implemented in nfs.

Answer (score 4):

A regular Linux NFS server would do the trick with the following combination of `/etc/exportfs` options:

```
all_squash,anonuid=xxx,anongid=yyy
```

Citing `man 5 exports`:

- `all_squash` - Map  all  uids  and gids to the anonymous user.
- `anonuid` and `anongid` - These options explicitly set the uid and gid of the anonymous account.

With Amazon EFS you'll need locally mounted `bindfs` layer to change permissions as the server export options cannot be changed.

Please take a look at [this Unix & Linux StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464209/equivalent-to-nfs-all-squash).

It looks like the `bindfs` currently lacks ability to map all users/groups into one but I guess it could be added to the code quite easily.

Comment: Thanks, bindfs might be that, eventhough I dont like the idea of having another program taking care of the permissions as a fuse bind. Reasons are performance, and stability. There is no automount option when something goes wrong with the NFS mount.

Comment: Not work for me to mount AWS EFS with command `sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport <filesystem id>.efs.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn:/ /mnt/efs`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just setting the user and permission on the files, do the job. So nfs is supporting standard fs file permissions and attributes.